# How do I get my HTML button to interact with my DOM properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I'm struggling to learn the DOM in JavaScript and figured hands-on practice would help solidify certain concepts. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on the very basics still; please bear with me. In my code, I am trying to program a button (id: tinkerHeaderButton) to change the background-color of my first header (id: headerOne) in my HTML to the color 'red', upon clicking.
I can't seem to progress past programming my first button however, and I feel like there's something very obvious that I'm missing. I have looked over several very similar posts and none of them gave me much insight into what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate anyone looking over my code and pointing out whatever the very obvious flaws are.

```js
//Header button and header variables
let tinkerHeaderButton = document.body.getElementByID("tinkerHeaderButton");
let header = document.body.getElementByID("headerOne");

//Event listener for header modifying button
tinkerHeaderButton.addEventListener("click", alterHeaderToRed);

//Function which should alter the background color of the first header in my HTML to the color 'red'
const alterHeaderToRed = () => {
    header.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
```

```css
body {
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle 610px at 5.2% 51.6%,  rgba(5,8,114,1) 0%, rgba(7,3,53,1) 97.5% );
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Supermercado One', cursive;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Marko One', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-large;
}

.header {
    background-color: rgb(20, 27, 27);
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border: 3px solid lightcoral;
}

.headerTwo {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 3px solid lightcoral;
}

.buttons {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    font-size: medium;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>| DOM Tinkering Grounds |</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DOM.css">
    <script src="DOM.js" async></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marko+One&family=Orbitron&family=Supermercado+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header" id="headerOne"> <!-- This is the header that I wish to modify -->
        <h1>DOM Tinkering Grounds</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="headerTwo" id="secondHeader">
        <h2>Tinkering Awaits!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
        <center><button class="buttons" id="tinkerHeaderButton">Tinker Header</button> <!--This is the button which should modify the header background color to 'red'-->
        <button class="buttons" id="tinkerContentButton">Tinker Content</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="tinkerButtonsButton">Tinker Buttons</button></center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I detected two errors:

1. Incorrect typing of `document.getElementById()` method.
2. Trying to use `alterHeaderToRed()` method before defining it.

```js
/* I updated the method below to be document.getElementById() . */
let tinkerHeaderButton = document.getElementById("tinkerHeaderButton");
let header = document.getElementById("headerOne");

/* I defined the method below before using it. */
const alterHeaderToRed = () => {
    header.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    console.log("The click event of the <button> element whose id attribute is 'tinkerHeaderButton' is fired.");
};

tinkerHeaderButton.addEventListener("click", alterHeaderToRed);
```

```css
body {
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle 610px at 5.2% 51.6%,  rgba(5,8,114,1) 0%, rgba(7,3,53,1) 97.5% );
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Supermercado One', cursive;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Marko One', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.header {
    background-color: rgb(20, 27, 27);
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border: 3px solid lightcoral;
}

.headerTwo {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 3px solid lightcoral;
}
.buttons {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    font-size: medium;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>| DOM Tinkering Grounds |</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DOM.css">
    <script src="DOM.js" async></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marko+One&family=Orbitron&family=Supermercado+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header" id="headerOne"> <!-- This is the header that I wish to modify -->
        <h1>DOM Tinkering Grounds</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="headerTwo" id="secondHeader">
        <h2>Tinkering Awaits!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
        <center><button class="buttons" id="tinkerHeaderButton">Tinker Header</button> <!--This is the button which should modify the header background color to 'red'-->
        <button class="buttons" id="tinkerContentButton">Tinker Content</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="tinkerButtonsButton">Tinker Buttons</button></center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, I knew the solution would be obvious. Thank you for putting an end to my frustration!

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.getElementByID` is incorrect
just use `document.body.getElementById`
and try to use intelligent IDE to help you Like Visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your code. They are listed below.

---

Instead of `document.body.getElementByID`, you need to use **`document.getElementById`**.

If you use an intelligent IDE, then it should help you with what variables or methods exist.

---

The code is written also has another issue, which is that you are using a function before it is declared.

---

The refactored code should look like the below. You can paste this into your JavaScript file.

```
// Updated both methods to use document.getElementById()
const tinkerHeaderButton = document.getElementById("tinkerHeaderButton");
const header = document.getElementById("headerOne");

// Defined the method before use!
const alterHeaderToRed = () => {
    header.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("The click event of the <button> element whose ID attribute is 'tinkerHeaderButton' is fired!");
};

tinkerHeaderButton.addEventListener("click", alterHeaderToRed);
```

Hopefully, this helped with your issue!